# What is the most elegant known proof of $m^*(A) \leq \sum_{n} m^*(A_n)$ when $A = \bigcup_n A_n$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $A = \bigcup_{n \in I} A_n \subset \Bbb{R}^k$ where $I$ is an arbitrary index set.  Define the *Lebesgue outer measure* by

> $m^*(A) := \inf \ \{ \sum_{n} \text{vol}(I_n) : I_n, n \geq 1$ are each any type of interval and $A \subset \bigcup_n I_n \}$.

Then how can we prove $m^*(A) \leq \sum_n m^*(A_n)$ elegantly.  The proof in my book is kind of hand-wavy and very complicated for something intuitively obvious.

Also this is the first property of such objects other than $m^*$ is monotonic: $A \subset B \implies m^*(A) \leq m^*(B)$.  First properties should be easily proven or something is wrong with the proof technique!  It has to be fixed.

So I am on the search for an elegant proof.  Maybe Galois connections?

The idea is that if I am successful, I can apply the proof technique to other such over-complicated examples I encounter.

Comment: Note that, for uncountable $I$, the inequality is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer assumes that $I$ is countable)

This is a case for the $\epsilon/2^n$ trick, in combination with the "give yourself an epsilon of room" trick. Once we've internalized these tricks the proof seems straightforward.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. For each positive integer $n$, let $\{I_{nj}\}$ be a countable collection of intervals such that $A_n \subset \cup_j I_{nj}$ and 
$$\sum_{j} |I_{nj}| \leq m^*(A_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}.
$$ 
Then

$$
A \subset \cup_{n,j} I_{nj}
$$
and

\begin{align}
m^*(A) &\leq \sum_{n,j} |I_{nj}| \\
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty |I_{nj}| \\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(A_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(A_n) + \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}}_\epsilon.
\end{align}

This shows that 
$$
m^*(A) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(A_n) + \epsilon
$$
for any $\epsilon > 0$. It follows that
$$
m^*(A) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(A_n).
$$

Comment: You should note that, in the question, the union was not necessarily assumed to be countable.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I thought about that, but sets with zero outer measure need not be empty. I don't see how the $\varepsilon / 2^n$ trick works in those circumstances.

Comment: When the union is uncountable the inequality is not true, so I'm not sure what you expect to prove.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I had a feeling that was the case. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Yes. $[0,1]=\bigcup_{t\in[0,1]}\{t\}$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Ugh, obviously. :-(

Comment: Does this hold for every monotonic $m^*$ such that ____ ?